# RESTful API,is an .htaccess file with rewrite rules really necessary

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, backbone.js

Many tutorials that describe how to set up a RESTfull api mention the use of an htaccess file to rewrite the url.
To be honest I do not quite understand where this is useful, **at least in my case.**
Let me explain.I am building an appointment web app.The user stores appointments in the db-and of course the intention here is that this is done via REST.

The calendar is shown in a page named calendar.php.From the moment the user goes there a GET operation is initiated by backbone to a page named events.php:

```
   var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Event,
    url: 'events.php'
     });
```

Events.php is suppose to have code related db queries-I say suppose, because I have not written any code there yet.To write the app I am studying this [tutorial](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/) here.

So here are my 2 questions:

1. Do you see any need here for htaccess and rewrite rules
2. The second question is why the url property in the tutorial(the code is found in the section titled **Bringing in Backbone** ) has as page just events(without the extension)-in that case htaccess would make sense,but why bother at all in the first place

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no reason that a "REST" interface to an application should require mod_rewrite or htaccess.

It's generally only useful if you want to retroactively rewrite e.g. old to new URL's (because someone messed up!).

People use mod_rewrite for all sorts of nonsense, sometimes where core pieces of the stack already do it -- for example mapping /foo to /foo.php (mod_negotiation) or by insisting that their implementation read a query string but their URL's look like PATH_INFO.

Comment: I understood your answer.I suppose that in my case, what you say, applies even more.Am I correct?

Comment: There is a fundamental conflict where people want to use .php in the filesystem but not in their URL.  There are multiple ways to accomplish this

Comment: can you be  more specific and how this related to REST.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone models/collections uses AJAX and RESTful resources to get and set data from and to the server. For example `collection.fetch()` will send `GET events.php` to get all items. And `model.save()` will send `POST events.php` or `PUT events.php/1` (where `1` is an `ID` of the model). Also when you need to get only one particular model data from the server it will send `GET events.php/1` (where `1` is an `ID` of the model). So you may to do not use `.htaccess` file at all for your simple requests. You can just get and `ID` from `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable in `PHP`.

Comment: So the author of the tutorial(http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/) he might as well  have used as URL,events.php.So concluding,URL rewriting is done for just having friendlier URLs-that is the point of it I think

Comment: The tutorial used ruby on rails so it didn't use apache and .htaccess at all to make `events` url. With apache we can't use php file as an url so we are trying to cheat with .htaccess and mod rewrite to send all requests from urls to one file which will handle URL routing.

Comment: From where did you reach the conclusion that the tutorial used ruby.The code I see in the tutorial is HTML and JS(backbone).Can the tutorial be used with PHP/MySQL-as it currently stands?

Comment: There is a link in comments to the source code https://github.com/shinetech/BackboneJsAndFullCalendar and yes it is possible to use PHP/MySQL as it is just backend and you can use your own.